# Remove some from list f#

Tags: list, f#

I have a list like this

```
let data = [{ A = "one"; B = 2020; C = Some 5L; D = None };
            { A = "two"; B = 2020; C = None; D = Some 3L}]
```

how do I replace `C = Some 5L;` with `C = 5;`

i want like this ->

```
[{ A = "one"; B = 2020; C = 5; D = null };
 { A = "two"; B = 2020; C = null; D = 3}]
```

i tried `let newData = data |> List.choose id`
It does not work.

Comment: What you want doesn't make any sense. Why do you want it like that?

Comment: this records comes from db C or D can be null or some int value

Comment: Then in your desired result you should have `C = null` instead of `C = None` and you can map it as ajuch suggests, to int? just setting it to null when it's none.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot have 2 different types in a list. `None` is of type `Option<int>` whereas `5` is type `int`. They cannot both be in the same list. The records are of different types.

Comment: i have updated the question. I do not know if int can have nullable type like in c#

Comment: Instead of nullable in F# you use the `Option` type. That is the correct way to handle possible missing values. Otherwise your code is unsafe.

Comment: No, that's what Option is for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use System.Nullable to represent nullable types that C# should recognize.
Also you will need to create a separate record type to represent your data with nullable fields.
I can imagine that you need to make this kind of transaction when leaving F# world and entering C#.

```
type A  = { A:string; B: int; C: int64 option; D: int64 option}
type T  = { A2:string; B2: int; C2: System.Nullable<int64>; D2: System.Nullable<int64>}
let data = [{ A = "one"; B = 2020; C = Some 5L; D = None };
            { A = "two"; B = 2020; C = None; D = Some 3L}]

let getNullable (x: int64 option) =
  match x with
  | Some v -> System.Nullable(v)
  | None -> System.Nullable()


let nullablData (data : A list)= 
  data |> List.map (fun x -> {A2 = x.A; B2 = x.B; C2 = getNullable(x.C); D2 = getNullable(x.D)})

let res=  nullablData data

//result
//val res : T list = [{A2 = "one"; B2 = 2020; C2 = 5L; D2 = null;};
//                    {A2 = "two"; B2 = 2020; C2 = null; D2 = 3L;}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to map the elements of the list into a different type. Since the record you are using inside the list looks like

```
type X = {
  A: string
  B: int
  C: int option
  D: obj option
}
```

and you want to have a

```
type Y = {
  A: string
  B: int
  C: int
  D: obj option
}
```

(mind the type for C), you need to transform the elements of the list with `List.map` using a function that maps type X into type Y.

```
data |> List.map (fun x -> { A = x.A; B = x.B; C = (x.C |> Option.defaultValue 0); D = x.D})
```

You have to handle the `C=None` case properly by giving it a default value.

Comment: I have updated the question. I can not have 0 when it is none.

Comment: In that case you can use `List.choose` instead of `List.map` to exclude the elements that have `None`. The function would be: `(fun x -> if x.C.IsNone then None else Some { A = .x.A  ...` where the rest is the same.